# Change img via css if it is out the container

Tags: html, css, image, width, imageset

I've got a container for image and img inside.

Is there some way to change the img content if it's width becomes bigger than the container width via css? Maby image-set?

```css
nav{; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height:70px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b8bbc0;
}

.logo-container{  
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 25%;
    flex: 0 0  25%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0  25%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}
.logo-helper{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo-container img{
    max-height:40px;
    margin: 5px;  
    display: inline-block;
    content:   url(https://wilcity.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/sample-logo-design-png-3.png);
}
```

```html
    <nav>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <span class="helper"></span>
        <img>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: If image is wider than the container I'd like to change it on another. For example, from the outset I've got rectangle image and going to change it on the square image

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally set any property in CSS because it is not a programming language.
You can do this in JavaScript.

```
var img = document.getElementById("my-img");
var container = document.getElementById("image-container");
if(img.style.width > container.style.width){
 img.src = "http://example.com/myimg.png"
```

}

Comment: Yeah, I know solutions via JS, but I wished there is some way to do it with CSS only. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tricky to change your code since you for some reason decided to use the content  - it is normally used for pseudo elements.

Here I use just src instead

```js
const img = new Image()
img.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const w = this.width, h=this.height;
  const container = document.querySelector(".logo-container");
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(container)
  const sW = parseFloat(style.width)
  const img = container.querySelector("img")
  console.log(w,sW)
  if (w > sW) this.src='https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=150px'
  img.src=this.src
})

img.src="https://wilcity.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/sample-logo-design-png-3.png"
```

```css
nav {
  ;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b8bbc0;
}

.logo-container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.logo-helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo-container img {
  max-height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I don't find it trikcy) In that way I can set elem.style.content = "src/another-image.png" just like img.src

Comment: @Alexandra Sure, but WHY? when you can do elem.src instead of (ab)using the content

Comment: :D
It was one of the ways to do it. Some css is contained in a file with vars, which is like a config-file. It's not a 100% right and final solution, it's just for a model)